# Strange Outlet Wiring - Now a Light is Always on

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit

I was replacing an outlet whose top receptacle never worked. When I got it out of the wall, I found that the neutral terminals were wired together (with a small s-curved wire). Two neutral wires and both a black and a red wire were also in the rear push connections. No matter what I've tried, the light in the room now does not turn off after the outlet was replaced (but the outlet works). I cannot get my head around how this circuit may be put together. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the small tab between the two hot screws missing/removed?  It is possible that half of that outlet is switched(on a switch for on/off), or each half of that outlet is on a separate breaker(MWBC).

Comment: Hi crip659 - looking at the old outlet, no - the tab is still there.

Comment: Do you know if there is conduit or cable for the wires?  Black, red and one white is common for /3 cables.  Red and white is very uncommon for /2 cables.  The extra white wire is odd/confusing without having conduit.

Comment: Is "the light in the room" a lamp this was plugged into *this* outlet, or a ceiling light, or plugged into a different outlet?   The details might impact the solution but regardless, I think you are now feeding unswitched power to the light from the formerly isolated unswitched half of the outlet.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it was a switched outlet, that was supposed to turn on when the light did. Now that it has been replaced with a new outlet that has presumably unbroken tabs connecting the top and bottom outlets, the switched and unswitched wires are connected, so the outlet is powering the light. Probably the red wire is switched power, and the black is always hot.

If you both receptacles in the outlet outlet to be always on and not switched, try disconnecting the red wire (cap it off with a wire nut). That will likely restore the expected behavior to your light.

On a side note, the push-in connectors on the back are not as reliable as the screw-in connectors on the side of an outlet.

Comment: Thanks Izzy - I will give your suggestion a try. I agree about the push connections - wholeheartedly. If this was a switched outlet, it never worked that way. Bizarre!